# What functions are called to display an (Array) variable on the julia REPL?

Tags: julia, read-eval-print-loop

Say I enter:

```
julia> X = randn(3,4)
3x4 Array{Float64,2}:
 -0.862092   0.78568     0.140078  -0.0409951
 -0.157692   0.0838577   1.38264   -0.296809 
  1.40242   -0.628556   -0.500275   0.258898
```

What functions were called to produce the output given?

Note that overloading Base.show does not seem to be sufficient to change this behaviour, so I'm unsure where to go.

```
julia> Base.show(io::IO, A::Array{Float64, 2}) = println("Humbug")
show (generic function with 120 methods)

julia> X
3x4 Array{Float64,2}:
 -0.862092   0.78568     0.140078  -0.0409951
 -0.157692   0.0838577   1.38264   -0.296809 
  1.40242   -0.628556   -0.500275   0.258898
```

Is it perhaps the case that I would have to change Base/array.jl source code and rebuild julia before such a change would work? Note the difference between this and a user defined type:

```
julia> type foo
       x::Float32
       s::ASCIIString
       end

julia> ob = foo(1., "boo")
foo(1.0f0,"boo")

julia> Base.show(io::IO, someob::foo) = print("Humbug!")
show (generic function with 123 methods)

julia> ob
Humbug!
```

Comment: `Base.show(X)` will give you the `Humbug`. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well, you should overload `display()`:

```
julia> Base.display(A::Array{Float64, 2}) = println("Humbug")
display (generic function with 11 methods)

julia> X
Humbug
```

you can find the definition in [REPL.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/a36bb6ddf585f57abed6885500a1bdc25126aee4/base/REPL.jl#L111-L117).